# Automate Twitter Bot

Tags: twitter, automation, bots

I have done a twitter bot using python that posts a tweet about the weather info for a specific city. I test it doing this: `python file.py` and then I check on my Twitter Account that it works. 
But, how can I execute it periodically? Where can I upload my source code? Are there any free server that runs my `file.py` for free?

Comment: Upload it to your server and do cronjobs. For short, cron jobs is like a scheduling the work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running gnu/linux and your machine is online most of the time, you can configure your own crontab to run your script periodically.

check: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html

If that is not the case,

Check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/FreeHosts for your purpose first from the list should do the job. (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can host your code file to a github repository, then run your .py file through a Github action which run by a schedule you set up by a .yml file at .github/workflows folder.